# php project Uncaught TypeError: Ajax is not a function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm setting up an apache server for a project using XAMPP, MySQL and PHP 5.6

And it seems that javascript hasn't been referenced right on the project, and i can't get it to work

(the problem is in the last line of code)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Ajax is not a function
at onload ((index):26)
```

I tried referencing jquery and js, many versions of them.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Gerenciador Clínico Odontológico Smile Odonto - Administração Odontológica Em Suas Mãos</title>
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="favicon.ico">
<link href="css/smile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.1.0/prototype.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.8.3/scriptaculous.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="lib/script.js.php"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="lib/ajax_search.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="MM_preloadImages('imagens/menu/inicio_f2.jpg','imagens/menu/arquivo_f2.jpg','imagens/menu/financeiro_f2.jpg','imagens/menu/atualizacoes_f2.jpg','imagens/menu/utilitarios_f2.jpg','imagens/menu/configuracoes_f2.jpg','imagens/menu/ajuda_f2.jpg','imagens/menu/sair_f2.jpg','imagens/menu/pacientes_f2.jpg','imagens/menu/pagamentos_f2.jpg','imagens/menu/fornecedores_f2.jpg','imagens/menu/caixa_f2.jpg','imagens/menu/agenda_f2.jpg','imagens/menu/estoque_f2.jpg','imagens/menu/telefones_f2.jpg'); javascript:Ajax('wallpapers/index', 'conteudo', '')">
```

Comment: Do you want to call jQuery `ajax()` function ? then do `$.ajax()` not `javascript:Ajax()` *these are not even the correct parameters for jQuery `ajax()`*.

Comment: This is not a php issue. See this example! https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

Comment: `Ajax()` is not a standard JavaScript function. The way you're calling it doesn't correspond with `$.ajax()`. So this is a function you need to define somewhere.

Comment: You also don't need to put `javascript:` in the `onload` attribute. That's only needed when you want to run JavaScript in place of a URL.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the function like this:

```
function Ajax(method, url, data = {}){

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   // new HttpRequest instance 
    xmlhttp.open(method, url);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify( data ));

    // catching the results
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {
          var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
          if (xmlhttp.status === 200 && response.status === 'OK') {
              console.log('successful');
          } else {
              console.log('failed');
          }
      }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Ajax('POST', '/wallpapers/index', { data : 'Some Content' });
```